# How can I modify the std::launch policy afterwards for std::async?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing, c++14, launch

Suppose I want to use `std::async` for parallelism in my c++ code to run a computationally heavy function `func`. Now since it is a heavy function, we might at first use `std::launch::deferred` policy for it as the situation is that we may not need to run after all.

But again if ever we need to execute them *suddenly* in the future, we desire to run in parallel. Then how can we modify the `std::launch` policy afterwards.

[Well, one can say that why don't you then *suddenly* create the `std::async`s as *suddenly* you need to execute. But I am assuming here that I cannot do that.]

Or, is there any better and cleaner way to do this other than using `std::async`?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<double> func(size_t n) // a computationally heavy function
{
    std::vector<double> vec(n);
    std::generate_n(vec.begin(), n, std::rand);
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    // create asyncs, now deferred for lazy execution
    auto v1 = std::async(std::launch::deferred, func, 200); // deferred for lazy execution
    auto v2 = std::async(std::launch::deferred, func, 250); // deferred for lazy execution

    // only after sometime we decide to execute both of them
    // but we also now want them to execute in parallel

    // so how can we now change the launch policy?

    // to get the values as quickly as can be
    auto n1 = v1.get().size();
    auto n2 = v2.get().size();

    std::cout<<"Got "<<n1<<" and "<<n2<<" random numbers in parallel!"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### UPDATE

Thinking a little bit more leads me with this issue:

After defining the `std::async` with `std::launch::deferred`, when one calls the `.get()` function, will it then be *guaranteed* to run *async* (i.e. in parallel) Surely, not. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch says

> it is executed on the calling thread.

Then the very notion of *async* gets spoilt, right?

Comment: Use a variable for your launch policy?

Comment: @Galik: how can I then use it?

Comment: Wait, do you want to change the lunch policy *after* creating the `std::async` object?

Comment: @Galik: Yes that's only after it is created!

Comment: I dont think that is (for now) using standard STL. If you create an async with deferred, it will not start until you call get(), so you may call get() "just" to start the calculation.

Comment: @ffslq: `async` is a simple tool for simple needs. If your needs are more complex, then you should build a tool that meets those needs, rather than relying on `async`.

Comment: @LeDYoM: But after defining the `std::async` with `std::launch::deferred`, when one calls the `.get()` function, will it then be guaranteed to run `async` (i.e. in parallel) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch says `it is executed on the calling thread`. Then the very notion of `async` gets spoilt, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `std::async` uses `std::launch::deferred` then it is run when the returned `std::future` object's `get()` function is called.

This suggests you could force `std::launch::async` like this:

```
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;

auto v1 = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []{ return 1; });
auto v2 = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []{ return 2; });

// some fancy coding ...

if(need_to_upgrade_launch_policy())
{
    auto v1a = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ return v1.get(); });
    auto v2a = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ return v2.get(); });

    s1 = v1a.get();
    s2 = v2a.get();
}

//  more clever coding ...

if(v1.valid()) // was never upgraded
    s1 = v1.get();

if(v2.valid()) // was never upgraded
    s2 = v2.get();
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be `[&]{return v1.get();})` and `[&]{return v2.get();})`? Seems like it is working. Thanks.

Comment: But still we are now creating yet another two `std::async`s. Anyway, it seems that this is the only way.

Comment: @ffslq Yeah, I updated the example to return values.